# What's the intermittent non-electrical buzzing sound my ceiling fan just started?

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans, noise

I switched the direction of my ceiling fan tonight and now it's making an intermittent zipping/buzzing sound. Here's some troubleshooting info:

-This isn't the first time I've switched the fan direction

-It is not electrical as the sound continues for a bit after I switch the power to the fan off

-It gets a little better and worse even running at the same constant speed. Faster or slower speeds don't really seem to impact it, although it stops entirely once it's going quite slow (like after the fan is turned off for 30 seconds and everything really slows down) and it takes about 5 or 6 seconds for it to initiate after being turned on

-When I initially switched the direction tonight, it made no noise. Then, some dust started coming off the blades and the noise began

-I cleaned the fan and used compressed air to blow into and around it hoping to maybe dislodge some dust from the inside but nothing came out and nothing changed

-I have tightened every screw I can see or access without disassembling anything

-If I heard the buzzing out of context, it would sound to me like the intermittent buzzing of a big insect flying by. It doesn't sounds metallic (though it could be) and my first thought upon hearing it was "Something got into the body of the fan and is zipping around." Don't know if that's the case, just trying to characterize it.

Comment: If you switch the direction again, does the noise stop?

Comment: Sadly no, I've tried switching it back and forth a few times since the initial switch and it keeps going.